# Scala case class is not matched in receive method (in akka actors)

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, akka, case-class

I have something like this:

```
class ProbeActor extends Actor {
  case class Probe(messageKey: String)
  def receiveProbe: Receive = {
    case Probe(probeKey) => println("Good probe: "+probeKey)
    case x => println("Bad probe: "+ x)
  }
  final override def receive = receiveProbe orElse receiveOther
  def receiveOther: Receive = {
    case _ => println("Other")
  }
}
```

and I call it like this:

```
class Prober extends ProbeActor {
  val definite = ActorSystem("ProbeTest").actorOf(Props[ProbeActor], name = "probed")
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 second)
  val future = definite ? Probe("key")
}
```

I expect the text `"Good probe: key"` should be printed, but I get `"Bad probe: Probe(key)"`.

**Note**: If I put the `Probe` case class outside, then it works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After searching more, I found an answer on [scala-lang.org](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/10052.html):

> I think the underlying misconception is about the identity of nested
>   class types.
>
> In
>
> class A { class B }
>
> each new instance of class A x creates a new type x.B. And if you do
>   the plain pattern match inside of A you are referring to the specific
>   instance of the type B this.B.

Comment: That's correct. I think by convention you should place your messages into companion object of an actor rather than into an actor itself. With that you should not have problems with dependent typing and you do not have to keep the reference to an actor, which is considered bad

Answer (score 2):

A way to pattern-match on `Probe` without moving it outside the class is

```
case probe: ProbeActor#Probe => println("Good probe: "+probe.messageKey)
```

Of course, moving it outside (e.g. to the companion object) is the better solution; particularly in Akka, as Archeg mentions, to avoid the direct reference to the actor.